# G is a simple graph with $n$ vertices and $\sum_{v \in V(G)}$$d(v) \choose 2 $$>(m-1)$$ n \choose 2$then G contains $K_{2,m}$

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if G is a simple graph with $n$ vertices and
$\sum_{v \in V(G)}$$d(v) \choose 2 $$>(m-1)$$ n \choose 2$then G contains $K_{2,m}$

I tried a proof by contradiction but all it gets me is that there is one vertix with degree at least m, but cant find a second one with the same exact neighbors, anyone got a lead to how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use contradiction by a counting argument:

Note $ {\sum_{v \in V(G)}} {d(v) \choose 2}$ counts the number of $K_{1,2}$ graphs in $G$. 
Let $S$ be the set of these $K_{1,2}$ graphs.

Now consider an arbitrary distinct vertex pair $v_1,v_2$. If $v_1,v_2$ appears as the 2-member partite set in a graph in $S$ at least $m$ times, we will be able to obtain $K_{2,m}$ by taking the union of $m$ of these graphs.

Suppose to the contrary that $G$ does not contain $K_{2,m}$. We count the elements in $S$ by noting the 2-member partite set of each graph.

By the previous argument each vertex pair $v_1,v_2$ appears as the 2-member partite set in a graph in $S$ at most $m-1$ times. There are at most ${n \choose 2}$ possible choices to obtain a vertex pair. So ${\sum_{v \in V(G)}} {d(v) \choose 2} \leq (m-1) {n \choose 2}$$ which is a contradiction.